# Function works in python shell alone, but not when called to another function?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

I have a homework issue with one of my functions called function 4. 
This is its code:

```
def getSuit(n):
    suits = []
    if 1 <= n <= 13:
        suits.append("Spades")
        return suits
    if 14 <= n <= 26:
        suits.append("Hearts")
        return suits
    if 27 <= n <= 39:
        suits.append("Clubs")
        return suits
    if 40 <= n <= 52:
        suits.append("Diamonds")
        return suits
```

Now the function works as it is if I call it into the shell like so:

```
>>>getSuit(51)
>>>["Diamonds"]
```

However, I am making a new function that sets the value of the card and also calls function 4 to obtain the suit of the card, but when I call the function it only displays ["Spades"] no matter what number is chosen.

Here is the code for Function 5:

```
def getCard(n):    
n = (n-1) % 13 + 1
deckValue = []
grabSuit = getSuit(n) # Called Function 4 here. <---
if n == 1:
    deckValue.append("Ace")
    return deckValue + grabSuit
if 2 <= n <= 10:
    deckValue.append(str(n))
    return deckValue + grabSuit
if n == 11:
    deckValue.append("Jack")
    return deckValue + grabSuit
if n == 12:
    deckValue.append("Queen")
    return deckValue + grabSuit
if n == 13:
    deckValue.append("King")
    return deckValue + grabSuit
```

So now when I call it into the python shell this is my output:

```
>>>getCard(52)
>>> ["King", "Spades"]
```

Whereas it should be:

```
>>>getCard(52)
>>>["King", "Diamonds"]
```

Am I just not calling the functions variable correctly, or do I need to rewrite function 4? I can't seem to figure out as to why it won't display the other suits despite it working just fine alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getCart` you change `n` before you use it with `getSuit()`

```
n = (n-1) % 13 + 1
grabSuit = getSuit(n)
```

change order

```
grabSuit = getSuit(n)
n = (n-1) % 13 + 1
```

Comment: Wow, haha I didn't notice that I did that. Bahh I feel like an idiot. Thank you for noticing that.

Comment: old method: use `print(...)` to see values in varaibles and which part of code is executed. Mostly it helps to resolve problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
def getCard(n):
grabSuit = getSuit(n) # Called Function 4 here. <--- Move to this line    
n = (n-1) % 13 + 1 
deckValue = []
```